# treeview item validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm trying to validate items inside a treeview. The main idea is that a user selects an object from the tree and that loads its details which can be edited. That's all working fine as I've got `INotifyPropertyChanged` hooked up but... my model has validation logic hooked up (`IDataErrorInfo`) and I'd like to show it in the treeview as well (highlight the item(s) which have validation errors).

I've tried some things already but I just can't figure out where to put the Validation in the binding to make it work like I would like it to.

My Validation ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="MyAdorner" />
                <Image
                                            MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=MyAdorner, Path=ActualHeight}" 
                                            MaxWidth="20"
                                            Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource ValidationIcon}, Converter={StaticResource UriConverter}}" 
                                            Margin="1" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

The treeView:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductCategories}"
              Name="treeView" SelectedItemChanged="treeView_SelectedItemChanged">           
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:ProductCategory}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductCategories}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
                                                    Value="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </StackPanel.Style>
                            <StackPanel.BindingGroup>
                                <BindingGroup />
                            </StackPanel.BindingGroup>
                            <StackPanel.ToolTip>
                                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                            </StackPanel.ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Medium" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProductCount, StringFormat='   ({0})'}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

Basically I'm trying to put a little icon next to the item in the treeview if the underlying Model has a validation error.

I've tried playing around with BindingGroup but that's a new topic for me so I'm not sure if that is even the way to go.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a couple of properties in your data class like the following:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Errors
{
    get
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> errors = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        errors.AddUniqueIfNotEmpty(this["PropertyToValidate1"]);
        errors.AddUniqueIfNotEmpty(this["PropertyToValidate2"]);
        ...
        errors.AddUniqueIfNotEmpty(this["PropertyToValidateN"]);
        return errors;
    }
}
```

This first one calls the indexer added for `IDataErrorInfo` and adds **all** validation errors into the collection if they are not already in there. The `AddUniqueIfNotEmpty` method is an extension method that 'does what it says on the tin'. I trust you can manage this part for yourself. The nice thing about this collection is that you can bind to it and see a collection of every validation error, not just one at a time like with the simple `IDataErrorInfo` implementation.

```
public bool HasError
{
    get { return Errors != null && Errors.Count > 0; }
}
```

The second property simply returns a `bool` that signifies whether there are any validation errors in the data object or not.

Then, you can simply bind to this property in your `Template` or `Style`. Here is an example that would change the colour of a `Border` if the relating data object had any validation errors.

```
<Style x:Key="ValidationBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError, FallbackValue=False}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```